# How to make Unity permanent and not temporary?

Tags: 11.04, unity

I recently upgraded to the final release of ubuntu 11.04. Was previously running my laptop on ubuntu 10.04 which was perfectly fine. After the upgrade, I noticed the panels were missing. I did a unity --reset and everything came back. Now the issue is that the panels are not permanent, every time I start my pc, I have to do a unity --reset. Can this be sorted?

Ubuntu Level: Novice

Answer (score 2):

Who wants to reset unity on every computer start up???

I had similar problem. Not after upgrading Ubuntu but when I was messing up with Compiz. So I'd say Pranav has something like Cube enabled or something similar and that is messing up his Unity.

So first I would reset all Compiz to default values, and second make sure that Unity plugin is checked in Compiz.

Answer (score 1):

- Open the dash by clicking on the top-left button (known as home button) or by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> (the one with the windows sign) key  and search for startup and open `Startup Applications` .

[image]

- Now click on the add button .

[image]

- Now enter a name in the name box and enter `unity --replace` in the command box.

[image]

- Add it and you are done .

Comment: I don't necessarily think this answer deserves a downvote, but it definitely seems more like a workaround than a fix.

Comment: `unity --reset` resets all your options. You don't really want that running at every log-in, unless you're happy with sticking with default settings forever.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Switch to tty1 (Ctrl+Alt+F1) and login as myself.
2. `rm -rf ~/.compiz` (in order to recursively delete session logs... there might also be `~/compiz-1` and so on --> delete all!)
3. `sudo service lightdm restart`
4. login using the standard greeter again.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/943083/comments/14